# GUI with fluid resizing behaviour

Tags: java, swing

is it possible using swing, to build a GUI whose elements, when the GUI is resized, keep te proportion between themself? Or i should fire a "resize every GUI component" function when the resize event occurs?
I'm using Netbeans 6.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long ago, there was a very interesting article series on JavaWorld about "[transmogrifying widgets](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-1999/jw-10-toolbox.html)" by [Allen Hollub](http://www.holub.com/). This serie explain how, using different widgets to sho the same information, a calcoulator can have different styles when viewed with different dimensions.

However, for a far simpler (but far less powerful) approach, you should take an in-depth look to [`GridBagLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) and the (now famous) [`GBC`](http://www.horstmann.com/articles/Taming_the_GridBagLayout.html) class. This will give you a fast, and quite elegant, method to resize your whole UI with interesting resizing behaviours (oh and don't forget the [associated tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)).

Answer (score 1):

I think that using traditional layout techniques is the best way to go - you generally want to choose which components resize and how they do it. However, if you really want a proportional resize then have a look at this answer:

[java swing resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302648/java-swing-resize/2305556#2305556)